# Converting RSS To JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to convert RSS to JSON but when I use console in Chrome I get this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.blastcasta.com/feed-to-json.aspx?feedurl=http://www.startalkradio.net/?page_id=354.
>   Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rss_url = "http://www.blastcasta.com/feed-to-json.aspx?feedurl=http://www.startalkradio.net/?page_id=354";

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : rss_url,
        succces : function(data) {
            $.each(data.rss, function(i, item) {
                $("#results").append('<ul>' + item.channel.item.description + '</ul>');

            });
        },
        dataType : 'json',
        async : true
    });

    function fetchRss(data) {
        $.each(data.rss, function(i, item) {
            $("#results").append('<ul>' + item.channel.item.description + '</ul>');

        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE**: this answer suggests using the Google Feed API which has been deprecated. Other options include Superfeedr: [Converting RSS to JSON](http://blog.superfeedr.com/convert-rss-to-json/)

That error happens because the RSS file is not in your server, so you are violating the Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Try this plugin that is used for cross-domain purposes with RSS:

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/11/cross-domain-rss-to-json-converter.html

**EDIT:**

**Library download link:**

http://code.google.com/p/lomodroid/source/browse/src/functions/jquery.jgfeed.js

**Live demo with twitter:**

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/NbDWb/

**Live demo with the link used in the question:**

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/NbDWb/3/

This will convert RSS to JSON

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.jgfeed.js"></script>
<script>
$.jGFeed('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/26767000.rss',
  function(feeds){
    // Check for errors
    if(!feeds){
      // there was an error
      return false;
    }
    // do whatever you want with feeds here
    for(var i=0; i<feeds.entries.length; i++){
      var entry = feeds.entries[i];
      // Entry title
      entry.title;
    }
  }, 10);
</script>
```

Comment: I can' seem to find the source for this plugin

Answer (score 1):

Well basically it is really simple. You cannot load that URL because JavaScript/your browser does not allow it. (Because of same origin policy).

You will have to do it with a scripting language (like PHP) or something, but not by JavaScript

Unless you have access to the source (RSS location) and can add headers to allow the origin

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Feeds API](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide) can do this easily. Just use the `google.feeds.Feed.JSON_FORMAT` result format. Here are [the docs](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide#resultJson) for that as well.

Comment: Be careful, Google Feeds API is shutting down.

Comment: Now it is completely shut down